# ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2 is always null on real device, works fine on SDK emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android, android-syncadapter

I'm writing a SyncProvider based on [Sam Steele's demo](https://github.com/c99koder/AndroidSyncProviderDemo).

However, I ran into a major problem. I write timestamps into the ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2 field. On the SDK emulator, this works just fine. On my Galaxy Nexus, however, it doesn't... Does anyone know why or how to fix that?

Here's my code:

*Writing the timestamp:*

```
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = '" + rawContactId + "'", null);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2, String.valueOf(timestamp));
operationList.add(builder.build());
mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
```

*Reading it out:*

```
    Uri rawContactUri = RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name)
            .appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type)
            .build();
    mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor c1 = mContentResolver.query(rawContactUri, new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, UsernameColumn, ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2 }, null, null, null);
    while (c1.moveToNext()) {
        SyncEntry entry = new SyncEntry();
        entry.raw_id = c1.getLong(c1.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
        long oldTimestamp = -1;
        if (!c1.isNull(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2))){
            oldTimestamp = Long.valueOf(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2)));
            Log.i("READ TIMESTAMP", String.valueOf(oldTimestamp));
        }
        entry.photo_timestamp = oldTimestamp;
        localContacts.put(c1.getString(1), entry);
    }
    c1.close();
```

For some reason, c1.isNull always seems to be true on the Galaxy Nexus. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Apparently, it *sometimes* gets written for a few contacts (1-5 out of >100), so I'm even more confused now...

**UPDATE:** I've checked the ContactProvider SQL db and the sync2 field really is empty, so it seems to be a problem with how I'm writing the timestamp.

Comment: a comment that is not the answer: you don't have to use getColumnIndex because you know the column in your Cursor. For example for ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2 is the third one: id = 2.